# Collection in express using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using express js with mongoose and saving data into users collection but i want to know how can i change collection name ? Here is my code

```
app.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => 
{
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/cuts');
    var User = require('./testing.js');

    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.name = req.body.name;
    newUser.email = req.body.email;

    newUser.save((err, User) => {
            if (err) {
               console.log(err);
            }
            else {
                   console.log("Signup Successfully");
            }
        });
});
```

Here is my testing.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type : String,
        required : true
    },
    email : {
        type : String,
        required : true,
        unique: true
    }
});
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go To your model and change your schemaname

```
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

To

```
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('NewUser', UserSchema);
```

Mongo Db by Defaults take plural name of your schema name.

Comment: i changed but still data is saving into "users" collection

Comment: r u want to rename your old collection or anything else please explain

Answer (score 0):

Collection name is fetched from Model itself. Please changing model name.

Change this

```
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

to

```
const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('NewUser', UserSchema);
```

Comment: @ Tushar Nikam: my first question is in above code i was not write "users" but data is saving into users collection and my second question is , as you say with your code now new collection will create "NewUser" and data will save into NewUser collection ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to renaming the existing User collection, use

```
const mongoose   = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cuts').then(() => {
  let db = mongoose.connection.db;
  return db.collection('User').rename('NewUserColl');
}).then(() => {
  console.log('rename successful');
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('rename failed:', e.message);
}).then(() => {
  console.log('disconnecting');
  mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

Comment: i dont want to update or rename existing collection , i am new in nodejs so i want to know that by default/first time , where should mention collection name ?